# How do I merge a EXR image with jpg images in opencv-python?

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

Hello I'm texture packing for a game, and wanted to merge the R, G channels of the normal map, the occlusion map (a multiplication of the ao and cavity map, but since I don't know how to multiply images in OpenCV properly I'm just using the cavity map), and the displacement map in EXR. The normal, and occlusion map are JPEG while the displacement is EXR, so I want to merge them while maintaining what I think is called the bit depth. Moreover I want to export this in a supported format which preserves the bit depth while also being compatible with engines like UE4, Unity, etc. Here's what I've got so far:

```py
normal = cv2.imread('{subdir}/{code}_4K_Normal.jpg'.format(subdir=subdir, code=code), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
ao = cv2.imread('{subdir}/{code}_4K_AO.jpg'.format(subdir=subdir, code=code), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cavity = cv2.imread('{subdir}/{code}_4K_Cavity.jpg'.format(subdir=subdir, code=code), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
height = cv2.imread('{subdir}/{code}_4K_Displacement.exr'.format(subdir=subdir, code=code), cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)

normal_b, normal_g, normal_r = cv2.split(normal)
ao_b, ao_g, ao_r = cv2.split(ao)
cavity_b, cavity_g, cavity_r = cv2.split(cavity)
height_b, height_g, height_r = cv2.split(height)

noh = cv2.merge((cavity_r, normal_g, normal_r, height_r))

cv2.imwrite('{subdir}/{code}_4K_NOH_2.tga'.format(subdir=subdir, code=code), noh)
```

But doing the above gives me this error:

```
noh = cv2.merge((cavity_r, normal_g, normal_r, height_r))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-h4wtvo23\opencv\modules\core\src\merge.dispatch.cpp:129: error: (-215:Assertion failed) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function 'cv::merge'
```

So here are the questions I'm asking:

1. How do i merge channels of different bit depths but still maintain the high bit depth.
2. Export the image to a good format, suitable for game engines.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to preserve high bit-depth with a TGA file, are you? What are you hoping to write RGB888 +D32 ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have no problem exporting to another file format then, thought TGA was high enough. Thanks for the info. Will edit post

Comment: @MarkSetchell Whats the meaning of the second question you are asking? Don't know enough about file formats to know.

Comment: What components (red, green, blue, depth, others?) do you need in the output file and what bit-depth should each one have? What are you planning to use the output file for/with?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The output has 4 channels, the normal's r and g, the r of the occlusion as the b and the r of the displacement as the a. I would prefer if only the alpha channel (displacement) was in high bit depth, though again idk how to do this.

Comment: @Apoqlite Hi In my Experience OpenCV library some time not gives the correct color value for Floating point EXR Images, So I refer OpenEXR Library to overcome the problem to get correct values, and there is some OpenEXR Link to help your problem hope it may help ==> https://gist.github.com/drakeguan/6303065

Comment: @13.tamil Hello, I have tried installing OpenEXR for python in windows using pip, but no matter how hard i try I just can't seem to install it. Which is why I attempted using the opencv way of doing it. Previously I used PIL, but I had a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about Unity or UE4, so if anyone knows better, please say and I'll happily delete these guesses/hints.

You have not specified what you mean by *"high bit depth"* - that could be 15, 16, 31, 32 or 64 bits per sample. Please clarify.

You seem to want a 4-channel RGBA output file.

So, given the above, all I can suggest is:

- maybe write a PNG if 16 bits or fewer per sample, or
- a TIFF otherwise.

You will need to make sure all channels are the same bit depth before you merge them. You may also need to scale them to be bright enough so as to be visible in their new high bit depth ranges. So, if you have an 8 bit channel from a JPEG and you want to make it 16 bit to merge with some other 16 bit channels, try:

```
HiDepthChannel = LoDepthChannel.astype(np.uint16)*256
```

Comment: ok so for my jpeg channels i do the code snippet above, but what for my exr channels? Do i just leave it as it is?

Comment: I don't know. You still haven't told us the bit-depth of your depth data. You need to do `print(height.dtype)`

Comment: Ok so I got it, the jpegs have uint8, whereas the exr has float32.

Comment: So `channel.astype(np.float32)*x`, is x still 256? Or do I not need to multiply anything?

Comment: Moreover I think it should be 255 not 256, since it goes from 0-1 to 0-255. I found out that I needed to do the following: `channel.astype.(np.float32)/255`

Comment: Well, the range of `uint8` is 0..255. The range of `float32` is +/- 3.4 x10^38. So you are either going to have to scale both to `uint16` and save as PNG, or scale both to float32 and save as TIFF. Again, you haven't said which way you want to go.

Comment: I converted everything to float32 and merged them together and it seems to work(only reason I say this is cause I'm skeptical if the exr maintains its bit depth, since OpenCV seems to have problems with EXRs)! Now as you said the only thing is the file format. I'm thinking of EXR or TIFF, which is why I converted to float32. What do you think will work?